# What is the difference between chunking and streaming in http?

Tags: java, http, streaming, chunking

I have a huge data filet hat backend is giving me.....i have to forward the same file to some other application ....Could someone please suggest what is the way to go streaming or chunking if both are actually different.

And if both are same thing do i have any other option using http protocol.

Comment: Why not use FTP, which is meant for stuff like this?

Comment: backend doesnt supports FTP

Answer (score 2):

There is no clear difference in performance between chunking and streaming . An advantage of streaming might be that :

Streaming doesn't cut latency, neither it cuts the time a dynamic response needs to be generated. But since the application sends content right away instead of waiting for the whole response to be rendered, the client is able to request assets sooner. In particular, if you flush the head of an HTML document CSS and JavaScript files are going to be fetched in parallel, while the server works on generating content. The consequence is that pages load faster.

This study might also give you couple of ideas since you didn't gave any details about the types of files you are trying to transfer :
[To chunk or not to chunk](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ebernard/nossd47.pdf)